# convert a hexadecimal into a decimal via string convert in java

Tags: java, hex, decimal

I want to convert a string hexadecimal into a decimal value i used Integer.decode but the value hast to be written by the user.

```
package hexa;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hexa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        
        String str1;
        System.out.print("Ingrese el hexadecimal= ");
        str1 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("From hex: " + Integer.decode("#str1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I'll add to my answer that this solution could have been found in ~0.23 seconds via Google.

Answer (score 2):

Use the overloaded [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method that takes a second parameter for the radix:

```
Integer.parseInt(str1, 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

For integer n

```
Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n), 16);
```